# TCP Client read error

Tags: android, tcp

I have a problem. In my IntentService I need to read some messages. I receive this messages from a server with TCP Connection. I've just implemented it in this mode:

```
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1000];

        StringBuilder reader = new StringBuilder();

        int counter = 0;

      while((counter=readeIn.read(bytes))!= -1) //if TCP Socket works
      {
            reader.append(new String(bytes, 0, counter));
            reader.append("\n");
            String req = reader.toString();
            Log.d("String received:",reader);
      }
```

and it works but in the logcat it prints the same string for 3/4 times...I think it's a problem of the buffer, but i can't use readLine() because server doesn't send me "\n"...
How could I solve it?
Thank you

Comment: you should print it after while loop

Comment: I've solved the problem myself! I don't use StringBuilder to build the String, but only a string!